# vectorizing nested for loops - pandas

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, pandas, vectorization

I have a case where multiple attributes from an 'outside' for-loop are compared to multiple attributes from an 'inside' for loop.

Both loops are on pandas dataframes, and from a little reading, using `iterrows()` for this sort of a job is generally going to be slow.

Below is an indication of how / why this nested for loop is being used. It is very slow.

```
for key1, values1 in dataframe_1.iterrows():        

    for key2, values2 in dataframe_2.iterrows():

        if values2['a'] > values1['a'] and value2['b'] == values1['b']:
            # do something, such as append to a combined df
```

Is there a more suitable way to perform these sorts of nested comparisons on pandas dataframes? Is a different datatype (i.e. a dictionary) a better place to start?

Comment: Comparing every row of one DataFrame with every row of another is inherently slow, since it's an O(m*n) operation.  What is the goal of this process?  Do you really need to compare every row with every other row?

Comment: Using `numpy` might benefit?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't to apply `for` loop or `iterrows()` at all in pandas:

```
for i in ((d2['a'] > d1['a']) & (d2['b'] == d1['b'])):
    # do something
    print i
```

Depending on what value want to do something with, you can alter the row:

```
(d2['a'] > d1['a']) & (d2['b'] == d1['b'])
```

to get the data needed to make some operation.